# Как правильно написать преЖДние или преЖние?

Tags: орфография

Какие ещё слова подходят под эту орфограмму?

Comment: Если вам дан ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

ПреЖние.
Относительно орфограммы — на чередование ***ж-жд*** достаточно много слов: ***утруждать — труженик***, ***вождение — вожу***. Вам это требовалось?
Очень похоже, что это д/з.

Answer (score 1):

**Если это орфографическая тема**, то она определенным образом связана с непроизносимыми согласными, например: звезда ― звездный. Сочетание ЗДН произносится как ЗН.

Но вот **слов с сочетанием ЖДН в русском языке нет**, так как старославянское ЖД заменяется русским Ж, если в слове появляется суффикс Н: **надежда ― надежный, прежде ― прежний, нужда ― нужный.**

**Это и есть примеры на заданную тему,  подходящие под эту орфограмму** (непроизносимые согласные). Можно сказать, что в приведенных словах нельзя сделать обычную проверку.

Другой вариант для прилагательных ― это **нулевой суффикс и окончание на гласную**, тогда ЖД сохраняется: чужой ― чуждый.

Таким образом, сочетание ЖД  пишется **перед гласными** (это сильная позиция для звука Д в сочетании ЖД): хождение, вождение, рождение. В слабой позиции перед согласными он не встречается.